# What's a portable and lightweight C/C++ regular expression library?

Tags: c++, c, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lightweight and portable regex library for C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923500/lightweight-and-portable-regex-library-for-c-c)

I'm looking for a C++ (C is acceptable, too) library for matching regular expressions. The library should satisfy these requirements:

- Can be built on Windows (MSVC 7 and newer)
- Can be built on Linux (g++ 3.4 and newer).
- Has no external dependencies; nothing but C/C++ runtime and STL allowed
- Works reasonably fast for small (~200 characters) strings to match against

I don't need a particular regexp flavor (POSIX, PCRE etc.) so anything is fine.

So far, I considered these libraries:

- [re2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/): Interesting, but apparently no support for Windows builds
- [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) doesn't seem terribly 'small' (over 1MB zipped sources) and doesn't seem to support Windows in its buildsystem.
- [Boost Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) might fit the bill but I didn't spend much time on trying to figure out if I can build it standalone

Anything else maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google for "pcre windows" seems to say that it does, in fact, support Windows. The `.so` file on my system is < 200 KiB, so it doesn't seem to take up that much disk space either...

Comment: I'm sure that it can be built on Windows somehow, but it seems I have to write the build system for it by myself. I'm looking for something with little to no *build time* dependencies as well.

Comment: Looking at the source code, it seems to use CMake, which can build on Windows. Does the build process fail at some point? All it should take is a simple `cmake ...; make` by the looks of it.

Comment: I went ahead and confirmed this: PCRE will build on Windows, and it's easy to do... `cmake path-to-pcre-source` followed by `nmake`. It builds Debug by default, but that's just an extra arg / an edit to the settings, which takes five minutes.

Comment: I'd +1 up you even more if I could for actually confirming your suspicion. :-} Good to know that it's not *that* hard to do. Now, maybe I should start using cmake for the rest of my codebase as well (I'm still working with handwritten Makefiles so far) so that the cmake build-time dependency of PCRE doesn't matter anymore...

Answer (score 3):

Try the GNU regex library.

http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

There's been at least one windows port:

http://people.delphiforums.com/gjc/gnu_regex.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Will give it a look.

Comment: I've used this library in a little program i developed on linux and cross-compiled for windows. The windows build used this library in the form of a dll (regex2.dll) ... I found the dll laying around the internet somewhere (probably gnuwin32.sourceforge.net); someone else had built it but it worked lika a champ.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ TR1 standard libraries contain regular expression classes. Newer versions of MSVC [contain an implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982382.aspx) and there is [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/) as a compiler independent implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, relying on TR1 features is (most likely) too much of a requirement. The MSVC implementation is not portable (obviously). Boost.Regex is compiler independent, but has too many dependencies (on other boost librarieS).

Answer (score 2):

Mine! But you have to download it as part of another tool - [csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/). The regex  code is in the alib  library, is based on the code in Software Tools In Pascal, ported with a lot of changes to C++. It is very small, about 30K or less of source, supports ed-style rexexes, compiles on Windows and Linux, and I would love to get others to improve it.

Comment: Out of curiousity: why did somebody (you?) port it to C++ instead of using another library? Or has it been so long again that there simply was no other library at that point?

Comment: @Frerich It is quite old code, and I don't like my FOSS projects being dependent on other projects if possible. But if you need real high-power regexes, you should obviously use something like boost - my csvfix project simply doesn't need that power.

Comment: @Frerich BTW, as someone who's name is always being misspelled, can I say that **French Raabe** which is how my failing eyes have always read it seems too me much cooler than your actual name :-)

Comment: @Neil: Hah! It does have a certain coolness to it, that's true. Maybe I should consider it as a nickname from now on. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[**Boost.Regex**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) would fit your bill in terms of compilers, though it has dependencies on other parts of Boost.

Comment: The dependencies are exactly what drives me away from Boost.Regex (as well as Boost.xpressive). :-/